# Unable to run Playwright test after Next.js version upgrade

Tags: next.js, playwright, e2e

I upgraded Next.js version from `12.0.10` to `12.2.2`. Now, when I run:
`yarn env PWDEBUG=console && playwright test --config=test/e2e/playwright.config.ts`,
it throws:

`Using config at /Users/jakubwasowski/Desktop/wishi/test/e2e/playwright.config.ts`
`Unknown or unexpected option: --config`

I totally can't figure out why it is happening. Downgrading Next.js version back to `12.0.10` solves the problem.

Somebody had similar problem?

Any hints?

Comment: Did you try with parameter -c <config file name>

Comment: Yea, it's the same - ``Unknown or unexpected option: -c``. What's weird here - before that error happens, I got ``Using config at /Users/jakubwasowski/Desktop/wishi/test/e2e/playwright.config.ts``, so it looks like calling config works, but then suddenly it crashes because of any passed arg

Comment: hey, Did you find a solution for this one?